# How to Invert a text in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert regular text to inverted form. is it possible in typescript?
regular text: how are you?
expected text: [image: expected text]

Comment: Under what scenario are you trying to do this? In HTML on a web page? Using unicode letters? Something else?

Comment: i am doing string processing in a cloud function to identify context and label the text accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be emulated by using typescript and a package that uses different letters that look similar e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/flip-text.

If you are thinking about using this in the context of a webpage this can be done far easier and cleaner by using (possibly type-script controlled) CSS though. Have a look at this for example: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-flip-text-with-css.html